# How do you paginate in solr using solarium?

Tags: php, solr, lucene, solarium

I am using solrium , a PHP Solr cilent  for using Solr with PHP , I am able to use queries like select etc . When I use select i get all only 10 results which is being set to 10 in default configuration in Solr , how do I get all results with Pagination  at the result?

here's the code

```
<?php



require('/var/www/lg/vendor/solarium/solarium/examples/init.php');

htmlHeader();

// create a client instance
$client = new Solarium\Client($config);


// get a select query instance
$query = $client->createQuery($client::QUERY_SELECT);




// this executes the query and returns the result
$resultset = $client->execute($query);


// display the total number of documents found by solr
echo 'NumFound: '.$resultset->getNumFound();

// show documents using the resultset iterator
foreach ($resultset as $document) {


$query->setStart(2)->setRows(10);

//$query->setStart(21)->setRows(30);
    echo '<hr/><table>';

    // the documents are also iterable, to get all fields
    foreach($document AS $field => $value)
    {
        // this converts multivalue fields to a comma-separated string
        if(is_array($value)) $value = implode(', ', $value);

        echo '<tr><th>' . $field . '</th><td>' . $value . '</td></tr>';
    }

    echo '</table>';
}

//new PageRequest(0, 10)

htmlFooter();





?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like: `$query->setStart(2)->setRows(20)` take a look at this example:http://wiki.solarium-project.org/index.php/V3:Usage_modes

And here is a little bit more about options you can give: http://wiki.solarium-project.org/index.php/V2:Building_a_select_query

Comment: Hey , thanks but I want only 10 results to be printed per page , and rest of the results should be paginated by 10 records . Just like google gives you page 1 , 2 , 3 .. results

Comment: Well you can change parameters, or i am missing something?

Comment: Changing Parameters will give me all the results in the single page on the browser , But I want only 10 results per page , and the next 10 results on the another page , and so  on .. did you get it ?

Comment: ok then change setStart accordingly, for example 1 page setStart(1), second 2,3,4... and just leave setRows(10) and you have pagination. setStart is offset in you resultset.

Comment: No , that dint work .. It will show the result of the last solr execution , i mean the last specified setStart(n) , not before that and no pagination

Comment: Wel it should work. even in manual it's described. start = 'Start position (offset) in the complete Solr query resultset, to paginate big resultsets.' http://wiki.solarium-project.org/index.php/V2:Building_a_select_query

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33005/discussion-between-aurimas-lickus-and-neetz)